# Conductance and concentration of a strong electrolyte

Tags: electrochemistry

I learnt that  with the increase of concentration, conductance of tr electrolyte decreases. While looking for the reason I found in my textbook that if concentration increase, amount of ions increases too. And for that ion-ion interaction gets a bit increased and lowers the speed of individual ions. Opposite thing occurs in case of dilute electrolyte solution.

But why is speed of ions even a matter here for concentrated solution? If the solution is concentrated, then availability of ions near electrodes increases a lot which means electrodes get a lot of charges to transfer from one to another a lot more than in dilute condition. That is current increases.

Can anyone please explain why does conductance really decreasd for increased concentration?

Comment: There were several  closely related questions for this topic. You may have not searched for them hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

In concentrated solutions, some ions are making groups of positive and negative ions which are not able to conduct the current, as if they would make a neutral assembly, as if there was a covalence between them.